# How to stop 'echo' from caching

Tags: linux, echo

I run the following:

```
echo -n apache2.conf | sha256sum

>> 02b957c917c42d01d99ed42e020415b3d5049c4b8945c65363fa8467bb4e0c6e
```

I then make a change to the apache2.conf file and run the command again, expecting a different hash, however it is the same hash which leads me to believe that echo is caching the file in that shell memory. When I open new shell and take a hash of the now-modified file it shows new hash.

How can I clear echo's cache or better still stop it from caching completely?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you confusing `echo` with `cat`? The former only prints its arguments, it does not treat them as filenames and dump their contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

echo will always print the name of the file which in your case is not changing.

Use **cat** command instead of echo to get the desired output.

Comment: Actually, in this case I would completely drop `cat` and only issue `sha256sum apache2.conf`.

Comment: @Hamidi, Indeed yes, cat can be completely dropped here, was just thinking in the perspective of user who created this question :-)